# SQL Server : how to check if a row exist in other tables

Tags: sql-server

I would like to ask for help if how can I write a T-SQL query that checks if a  row exists in other tables and insert the data in a temporary table.

For example, I have 5 tables `main1`, `table2`, `table3`, `table4` and `table5`. Each table has a `product_id` column.

I need `main1.product_id` (values A000 to A010) to check if they exist in `table2`, `table3`, `table4` and `table5`.

If it is found in `table2`, the value "A000" will be inserted into a temporary table. If it is not found, it will check in `table3`; again if not found, it will check in `table4`.

Then `main1.product_id` value "A001" will be checked. If A001 is found in `table2` it won't be checked in `table3` and `table4` anymore, it will be written into the temp table and next value is to be checked from `main1` table, and so on,...

Thanks so much

Comment: you have to check your statement according to your case `IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM tableNamw WHERE columnName = @param)`

Comment: thanks for the comment. but can you give me an example for data i need?

Comment: You should create example of this by editing your question, what rows are in each of the tables and what you expect as a result.

Comment: Hi JamesZ, i already edited my question. thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're looking for something like this:

```
insert into #tmp
select product_id
from main1 m
where
(
  exists (select 1 from table2 t where t.product_id = m.product_id) 
  or exists (select 1 from table3 t where t.product_id = m.product_id)
  or exists (select 1 from table4 t where t.product_id = m.product_id)
  or exists (select 1 from table5 t where t.product_id = m.product_id)
)
```

This will check each of the tables, and if the row is found, inserts it into #tmp

Comment: hi jamesZ, cars10, will this statement terminate and check on the next record if product_id be found on table2? or will it still continue to check on table3? thanks

Comment: @Mc888 As far as I know it will stop for the first match it finds

Answer (score 0):

Or, alternatively, you could just use `UNION ALL` like in

```
Insert into #tmp
Select product_id from main1 where exists
(select 1 from (
  select product_id p from table2 union all
  select product_id from table3 union all
  select product_id from table4 union all
  select product_id from table5 
  ) all where p=product_id )
```